# python classes, def __init__(): and input statements

Tags: python

I am trying to define a class called 'Vacation' to store information about the user once they have answered a set of input statements (my project is a vacation program where the user answers a set of questions in order to receive a randomly generated vacation itinerary). My professor told me to put all of my questions (aka input statements) within my constructor, however I keep getting an error saying I have a syntax error although I am not sure why. I have tried putting the different variable names in the () of my constructor but this does nothing (I thought maybe I had a syntax error because I forgot to include one of the variable names - specifically the error is coming from 'excursions'). I am fairly new to Python (just started in January) so my knowledge of the programming language is very limited (plus I just learned classes about 2 weeks ago). Any and all help/feedback/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
class Vacation:                  
    def __init__ (self, num_guests, max_price, vacay_len, excursions, user_input, excursions_price, excursions_num, user_preference):
        user_input = input("Would you like a (R)andomly generated vacation or a (T)ailored vacation?: ")
        num_guests = int(input("Please enter number of guests: "))
        max_price = float(input("Please enter your maximum willingness to pay (ie. 700): "))
        vacay_len = int(input("Please enter how many days you would like your vacation to be: ")
        excursions = (input("Would you like to include excursions while on vacation? (Y/N) : ")).upper()
        if excursions == "Y":
            excursions_num = int(input("How many excursions would you like to sign up for (up to 2): "))
            excursions_price = float(input("How much would you like to spend on each excursion? : "))
        else:
            print("Let's get to exploring!")
        user_preference = user_input
        self.user_preference = user_preference
        self.num_guests = num_guests #number of guests
        self.max_price = max_price #maximum price range
        self.housing_price = .3(self.max_price) #housing budget allocation 
        self.vacay_len = vacay_len #vacation length
        self.excursions_price = excursion_price #price for each excursion  
        self.excursions_num = excursions_num #number of excursions
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you're getting? Also show us the code that is creating an instance of your Vacation class. - Putting the variables in the () of your constructor is probably not what you want.  If you do this, you are saying that you're going to pass in those values to your constructor when you create an instance of your class.  Since you set at least some of those value in your constructor, it's doing you no good to have them be parameters to your constructor, as you're overwriting any data you would pass in via those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing bracket on this line:

```
vacay_len = int(input("Please enter how many days you would like your vacation to be: "))
```

You have a typo `excursion_price` should be `excursions_price` as below:

```
self.excursions_price = excursions_price #price for each excursion
```

You also need to add `*` for multiplication here:

```
self.housing_price = .3*(self.max_price)
```

You can remove the variables from the `__init__` function in this case since they will be provided by the users input to the programme.

I would recommend using a python IDE which will highlight the issues for you in red.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but the following code seems to work:

```
class Vacation:
    def __init__ (self):
        user_input = input("Would you like a (R)andomly generated vacation or a (T)ailored vacation?: ")
        num_guests = int(input("Please enter number of guests: "))
        max_price = float(input("Please enter your maximum willingness to pay (ie. 700): "))
        vacay_len = int(input("Please enter how many days you would like your vacation to be: "))
        excursions = (input("Would you like to include excursions while on vacation? (Y/N) : ")).upper()

        if excursions == "Y":
             excursions_num = int(input("How many excursions would you like to sign up for (up to 2): "))
             excursions_price = float(input("How much would you like to spend on each excursion? : "))
        else:
            print("Let's get to exploring!")
        user_preference = user_input
        self.user_preference = user_preference
        self.num_guests = num_guests #number of guests
        self.max_price = max_price #maximum price range
        self.housing_price = .3(self.max_price) #housing budget allocation
        self.vacay_len = vacay_len #vacation length
        self.excursions_price = excursion_price #price for each excursion
        self.excursions_num = excursions_num #number of excursions
```

As suggested by Steve I removed your variables from the constructors parameters as you probably won't be passing arguments. At the Excursions line you were simply missing a closing `)`